# Elasticsearch install localhost:9200 can't connect, and no log files to review

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

Nevermind **L** and **K**, **E** is not functioning.

So what gives? What does it take to get a functioning elasticsearch install?

**============= Installation hardware:**

```
Raspberry Pi 3+
Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)
```

**============= Installed via apt:**

```
sudo apt-get install elasticsearch

Setting up libelasticsearch1.7-java (1.7.5-1) ...
Setting up elasticsearch (1.7.5-1) ...
```

I went to change `/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml` as the installation instructions say.

All the lines were commented so I uncommented 3 lines and added config info per the instructions:

```
network.host: 0.0.0.0
http.port: 9200
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
```

**============= Elasticsearch is running as a service, according to the install:**

```
$ sudo service elasticsearch status
● elasticsearch.service - LSB: Starts elasticsearch
Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/elasticsearch; generated; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: active (exited) since Tue 2019-05-21 02:53:17 PDT; 2min 52s ago
Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
Process: 21421 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/elasticsearch stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 21455 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/elasticsearch start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

May 21 02:53:17 xxxx systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Starts elasticsearch...
May 21 02:53:17 xxxx systemd[1]: Started LSB: Starts elasticsearch.
```

**============= But it's not listed in the active connections:**
$ sudo netstat -natp

```
[PRIVATE DATA]
```

**=============  Testing the installation:**

```
$ curl http://localhost:9200
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9200: Connection refused
```

There are no log files:

```
$ sudo ls -l /var/{log,lib}/elasticsearch
/var/lib/elasticsearch:
total 0

/var/log/elasticsearch:
total 0
```

Without any logs, there's no way to track down anything. And setting the log.path did not create any log files.

Comment: I think correct setting for log path is `path.logs`, so can you try with `path.logs: /usr/local/var/log/elasticsearch/` and `path.data: /usr/local/var/elasticsearch/`

Comment: Transposition error in writing the request for help.

Comment: sorry i didn't get you.. did you restart es after this change ...

Comment: Yes. I restarted. Same error.

Comment: which error, you were saying that it doesn't give any error.. can you paste your error

Comment: The error which is the title of my question. There are no logs being written.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193738/discussion-between-amit-khandelwal-and-ken-ingram).

Comment: were u able to resolve this issue

Comment: Yes. I installed it from a debian package: sudo dpkg -i elasticsearch-7.1.0-amd64.deb

Comment: I was able to get elasticsearch running. Got stuck on Kibana and logstash. I believe I need logstash to pull info from the mysql instance holding the data.